# How to segregate strings starting with a certain value into a separate column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data and I would like to have all the values starting with SAR into the "price" column. The "SAR" values are scattered all over the dataframe.

```
name,rating,random,price
"Microwave Oven Sharp 20 Litres, White, R-20AS-W",5.0 out of 5 stars,3,SAR 199.00 
"REBUNE ELECTRIC OVEN 10L, RE1016",SAR 149.00 ,,
Geepas 20 Liter Microwave Oven - GMO1894,SAR 186.00 ,,
Nikai Microwave - 20 LTR -NMO515N8N,5.0 out of 5 stars,3,SAR 192.15 
LG 42 Liter Neo Chef Inverter Microwave with Grill - MH8265CIS,"SAR 1,050.00 ",,
```

I want it like below. Where the data is unavailable it should write "Unavailable":

```
name,rating,random,price
    "Microwave Oven Sharp 20 Litres, White, R-20AS-W",5.0 out of 5 stars,3,SAR 199.00 
    "REBUNE ELECTRIC OVEN 10L, RE1016",Unavailable,Unavailable,SAR 149.00 
    Geepas 20 Liter Microwave Oven - GMO1894,Unavailable,Unavailable,SAR 186.00 
    Nikai Microwave - 20 LTR -NMO515N8N,5.0 out of 5 stars,3,SAR 192.15 
    LG 42 Liter Neo Chef Inverter Microwave with Grill - MH8265CIS,Unavailable,Unavailable,"SAR 1,050.00 "
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. What have you done? Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to split the string into a series of lists to work with:

```
a = ''' "Microwave Oven Sharp 20 Litres, White, R-20AS-W",5.0 out of 5 stars,3,SAR 199.00 
    "REBUNE ELECTRIC OVEN 10L, RE1016",Unavailable,Unavailable,SAR 149.00 
    Geepas 20 Liter Microwave Oven - GMO1894,Unavailable,Unavailable,SAR 186.00 
    Nikai Microwave - 20 LTR -NMO515N8N,5.0 out of 5 stars,3,SAR 192.15 
    LG 42 Liter Neo Chef Inverter Microwave with Grill - MH8265CIS,Unavailable,Unavailable,"SAR 1,050.00 " '''

# split string starting from SAR into a list, resplit each string in the list starting with space, ignore first occurance
b = [x.split(' ')[0] for x in a.split('SAR ')][1:] 

# convert to float
c = [float(x.replace(',','')) for x in b]
```

Comment: b = [x.split(' ')[0] for x in df.split('SAR ')][1:] 

# convert to float
c = [float(x.replace(',','')) for x in b]
I tried it and Im getting the below error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

I would not use pandas here, but stick to the good old `csv` module, because the file can be processed at a row level while the strength of pandas comes when you process columns.

The algo is simple: test all fields from a row to see whether they start with SAR and move it to the price column setting it to `Unavailable`, and set it too to `Unavailable` if it is empty.

Code could be:

```
with open('input.csv') as fdin, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    na = 'Unavailable'
    rd = csv.reader(fdin)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    _ = wr.writerow(next(rd))   # copy header
    for row in rd:
        for i in range(len(row) - 1):
            if row[i].startswith('SAR'):
                row[3] = row[i]
                row[i] = na
            elif len(row[i]) == 0:
                row[i] = na
        if len(row[3]) == 0: row[3] = na
        _ = wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: @raptorzee: the header line must be copied *as is* with no additional processing...